# Does packages.ubuntu.com provide a search API?

Tags: source-packages

The Debian package directory provides a simple API to search for package releases. For instance [this query results](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libtry-tiny-perl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) can be accessed as JSON at https://sources.debian.net/api/src/libtry-tiny-perl/. Is there a similar API for http://packages.ubuntu.com/?

Comment: Since everything in Ubuntu is on Launchpad, you can probably use [Launchpad's API](https://help.launchpad.net/API/) to do something similar.

Answer (score 6):

As commented by [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), everything in Ubuntu is on Launchpad. [Launchpad's API](https://help.launchpad.net/API/) can also be used to search for package releases. To give an example:

- package [libtry-tiny-perl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtry-tiny-perl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) at packages.ubuntu.com
- package [libtry-tiny-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libtry-tiny-perl) at Launchpad
- package [libtry-tiny-perl](https://api.launchpad.net/devel/ubuntu/+source/libtry-tiny-perl) at Launchpad API (limited response)

To get API response as JSON, use curl:

```
$ curl https://api.launchpad.net/devel/ubuntu/+source/libtry-tiny-perl
```

Package releases can be queried with query parameter 
`source_name`at base URL https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/ubuntu/+archive/primary?ws.op=getPublishedSources&&exact_match=true, for instance:

```
$ curl 'https://api.launchpad.net/1.0/ubuntu/+archive/primary?ws.op=getPublishedSources&source_name=libtry-tiny-perl&exact_match=true'
```

The API documentation is a bit complicated, even with the official API client [launchpadlib](https://help.launchpad.net/API/launchpadlib) so it took me some time to find out. The Ubuntu version of a package release is given in field `distro_series_link`.