# Web Api for list of packages available in ubuntu, Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)?

Tags: apt, package-management

I tried to search an open public api for getting the list of packages available in **Advanced Packaging Tool (APT)**, but was unable to find any. Could anyone point me to the right direction. Following are my use case:

- Get the list of apt packages available
- Get a small description corresponding to the package, along with the website, if any.
- Download stats for that particular package

Comment: It's pretty easy to simply parse the data from /var/lib/apt/lists, since you seem to want data on all packages in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: Otherwise, you seem to be looking for the `apt-cache` command, which has options to provide exactly what you seem to be asking for. See `man apt-cache`

Comment: @user535733 I'm looking for web api. Not  local machine

Comment: Apt (deliberately) cannot be remotely controlled (or queried) by web interface, whether local or remote. Apt does not listen for web connections. The only web-related apt package is `apturl`, and it (deliberately) doesn't do any of the actions you are asking for. It's pretty much that simple. The only remote-control apt application is Landscape, a proprietary application sold by Canonical.  Most folks use SSH to login to a remote machine and use apt from there. Volume users purchase Landscape or roll their own SSH-based solutions.

Comment: see https://askubuntu.com/questions/620956/does-packages-ubuntu-com-provide-a-search-api

Comment: What would this be for? Could you host a web server? You could install webmin and tweak the file software/tree.cgi to display a list of installed packages, and software/edit_pack.cgi and software/list_pack.cgi to display details of the package.